# Bundler: Could not local Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm moving some ruby projects over to an Ubuntu machine, and am trying to install the dependencies.

I've installed `ruby-full` and the bundler gem. When I move to the project directory and type `bundle install` I get the error `Could not locate Gemfile`

I am in the correct directory, and the GemFile is there.
If I ls the current directory, I see:

```
etrax_connect.rb  fujixml.bat  fuji_xml.rb  GemFile  GemFile.lock  generate_subject_xml.rb  logging.rb  prawn_functions.rb  README.md  samples  sftp_connect.rb
```

Its RIGHT there.
The contents of my GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'listen'#file listening
gem 'nokogiri'#xml parsing
gem 'rake'#Globbing
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'prawn'
```

I dont understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `GemFile` to `Gemfile`, and also `GemFile.lock` to `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Wow. I guess windows never carded about the case cause' it's windows. Thanks a ton.